# Run "java -jar MyJar.jar" automatically on linux server, instead of on login and run from ssh

Tags: java, linux, shell, tty

How can I run a Java .jar file, fx "java -jar MyJar.jar" automatically on a Linux server, instead every time I login and run it from ssh?

I am looking for some way to automatically execute that command, or something to that effect.

Also, how can I direct all output to some logfile? (I guess stdio in autostrt is unavailable.)

Comment: Upstart helped me here. upstart.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the terminal hooks, like [See this answers about the bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal). When you make a login or open a new terminal on your server, the script will run and execute your script.

Answer (score 2):

Since you reference "ssh", I'm gonna guess you are on *nix.

Have a look at cron

Redirecting output in *nix is easy, just use the ">" and "2>" redirections.