# How to run .jar continually and automatically on Debian server?

Tags: java, ssh, jar, cygwin, debian

I have a `.jar` file I want to run all the time on a `Debian` server.

Currently I have figured out how to access the server via `ssh` on `Cygwin` and start the `.jar`. But when I close the Cygwin window on my development machine, it kills the process on the server (I think, as it's not responding any longer).

Currently I start it like this:

```
java -jar myjar.jar packageName.fileNameOfFileWithMainMethod
```

I need to make this file run automatically and continually on the server (it is an integral part of the system I am developing).

Unfortunately I know next to nothing about server management, or non-windows operating systems in general (wasn't me who chose or made the server), so I really don't know what to do, nor what to search for (apparently, since my searching gave no usable results).

I have read (and edited because the text was a mess) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250843/run-java-jar-myjar-jar-automatically-on-linux-server-instead-of-on-login-and) question, but although I feel it might be hinting in the right direction, I didn't get much help from it. I also tried my best googlefu, but it got me a lot of only tangentially related results.

I guess I'll have to make some kind of script (possibly containing the code line above), do some stuff to it and put it somewhere specific on the server to accomplish what I want to do.

Would someone be so kind as to explain how this is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple suggestion would be to run the jar file using Linux's [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

[This article from unix stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98914/how-to-use-crontab-for-a-java-file-in-linux) should get you going the correct direction for running a jar file using cron.

Alternatively, [this article from mkyong.com](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-cron-job-to-run-a-jar-file/) is also clear and concise.

For example:

1. Connect using Cygwin
2. Run `crontab -e`
3. Enter `0 * * * * java -jar myjar.jar packageName.fileNameOfFileWithMainMethod` to run the jar file every hour at the top of the hour. Or, to start it once on server startup enter `@reboot java -jar myjar.jar packageName.fileNameOfFileWithMainMethod`

Comment: So I might want to make cron job scheduled with the `@reboot` scheduling?

Comment: Not quite. The `@reboot` scheduling will cause the job to be executed once when the server is started. From the sounds of it this is not what you want! Have a read of the mkyong.com article. I think this is probably the simplest i.e. `crontab -e` then specify how frequently you'd like the jar file to run

Comment: My java program is a port-listening server and will only stop running if actively stopped. Actually, trying to start it again while running might cause problems.

Comment: OK. Sounds like `@reboot` is what you want then!

Answer (score 2):

Shell hooks are good for configuring user environment variables.

**Cron** is for scheduled jobs, mostly related maintenance, such as creating backups, managing log-files etc ...

Background processes with **nohup** as advised by Николай Митропольский, or ssh with "**screen**" application (which let you detach/reattach to a "session"), will be useful in development time.
But can not handle server shutdown cleanups, or respond to restarts.

**Init scripts** mentioned above is the standard way to start/stop services.

There is an application named **init**, which is the first application started when a Unix-like system boots.
Init, according to **runlevel**, starts some scripts, and those scripts manages **daemons** (services in Windows).
So for services, you write "hooks" for [runlevels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel#Linux_Standard_Base_specification),

In Debian, **/etc/init.d/** where you put your init scripts,
you can read the scripts inside this folder to get the idea,
they are text files (bash scripts).

Those scripts are called with an argument
(a standard keywords, such as "start", "stop" etc..).

**/etc/rc?.d/** (where ? is one of runlevels), where the init finds the scripts to run.
But those scripts are just "automatically created" symbolic links to the scripts in /etc/init.d/.
You do not need to touch anything inside /etc/rc?.d/ folder.
*After putting your script into /etc/init.d/,
you only need to call to create symbolic links *:

```
sudo update-rc.d "your-scripts-name" defaults
```

As you see there are some prefixes attached to names of scripts;
for example **/etc/rc1.d/K10apache2** which is a symbolic link to **/etc/init.d/apache2**.
So a simple "ordered by name execution" is possible here.

Automatically creating those prefixes (so the execution order), 
dependency information is required.
So init scripts includes this information.
Also information required when (at which runlevel) those scripts should be called (with "start" or "stop").

This dependency information is placed as comments in those scripts.
Forexample apache server init script (**/etc/init.d/apache2**) includes those lines;

```
# Provides:          apache2
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
```

Detailed information exists in Debian policy;
https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s-sysvinit
also this will be usefull;
https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_2.1.0/LSB-generic/LSB-generic/iniscrptfunc.html

NOTE:
*There is a huge transition and debates/fragmentations in Unix world.

Init and init scripts, tradationally used in Unix/Unix-like systems, nowadays becoming obsolete on many systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init#Replacements_for_init

Debian currently uses **systemd**, but **init scripts** still works with systemd (systemd provides the compatibility).*

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to detach process by using `nohup` with `&`:

```
nohup java -jar myjar.jar packageName.fileNameOfFileWithMainMethod &
```

to stop process will be possible with `kill <process-id>` command

process id could be found by `ps -ef  | grep packageName.fileNameOfFileWithMainMethod`

But if you are developing serious application that is long-running on server you have to deal with initialization system like **systemd**, **upstart** or something like that.